# Collection property not properly added to parent on save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Look at the following code example.

What it does:

1. Iterates a bunch of customers. If it already knows the customer, it retrieves the existing database object for that customer (this is the problem-ridden part). Otherwise, it creates a new object (this works fine).
2. All loans where the social security number matches (CPR) will be added to the new or existing customer.

The problem: it works for new customer objects, but when I retrieve an existing customer object, the loans lose their relation to the customer when saved (CustomerID = null). They are still saved to the database.

Any ideas?

```
protected void BuildCustomerData()
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Starting the customer build.");

    var counter = 0;
    var recycleCount = 100;
    var reportingCount = 100;

    var sTime = DateTime.Now;

    var q = from c in db.IntermediaryRkos
            select c.CPR;

    var distincts = q.Distinct().ToArray();
    var numbersToProcess = distincts.Count();

    Console.WriteLine("  Identified " + numbersToProcess + " customers. " + (DateTime.Now - sTime).TotalSeconds);

    foreach (var item in distincts)
    {
        var loans = from c in db.IntermediaryRkos
                    where c.CPR == item
                    select c;

        var existing = db.Customers.Where(x => x.CPR == item).FirstOrDefault();

        if (existing != null)
        {
            this.GenerateLoanListFor(existing, loans);
            db.Entry(existing).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                CPR = item,
            };

            this.GenerateLoanListFor(customer, loans);
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.Entry(customer).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
        }

        counter++;

        if (counter % recycleCount == 0)
        {
            this.SaveAndRecycleContext();
        }

        if (counter % reportingCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    Processed " + counter + " customers of " + numbersToProcess + ".");
        }
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}

protected void GenerateLoanListFor(Customer customer, IQueryable<IntermediaryRko> loans)
{
    customer.Loans = new List<Loan>();

    foreach (var item in loans.Where(x => x.DebtPrefix == "SomeCategory").ToList())
    {
        var transformed = StudentLoanMap.CreateFrom(item);

        customer.Loans.Add(transformed);

        db.Entry(transformed).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

As pointed out, I am manually setting the state. This is due to the RecycleContext call, which is implemented for maximum db transaction performance:

```
protected void SaveAndRecycleContext()
{
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Dispose();
    db = new SolutionDatabase();
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I'd think the db recycling issue might be better managed by a using clause and scope management

Comment: Good tip, but it does not solve the current problem.

Comment: Re-enabling AutoDetectChangesEnabled and ValidateOnSaveEnabled does solve the original problem, but introduces a very large performance hit which I cannot accept. It is already a pretty operation that requires about an hour. With those features enabled, that would be about 4-5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Existing loan or not, you wipe out the customer.Loans Property when you call

`customer.Loans = new List<Loan>();`

Comment: True. I have tried with or without that line. Does not matter. However, as I need to renew the loan data each time, it is okay to wipe the list every time.

Comment: you are also manually manipulating the `.State` property instead of letting it go with what it believes is right for each one.